# does mysqli_insert_id only work if I have a column called ID?

Tags: database, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

Hello I was wondering that if I use the mysqli_insert_id function will this only insert an auto increment id value if I have a column called ID because at the moment I have one called UserID and I was wondering if this would cause problems for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column doesn't have to be called `ID` in order for `mysqli_insert_id` to be useful, but you do have to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, and i'm fairly certain it has to be the primary key.

The way you're describing it, though, it sounds like you might be misunderstanding what `mysqli_insert_id` does.  It doesn't *insert* an ID; it returns the last auto-generated ID it assigned.  So you use it after you've inserted a row, if you want to use that ID to add other records that refer to the row you just inserted.

Comment: This makes sense now, I was misunderstanding what it does, Thanks